# How to get a smooth look like this?

Tags: mesh

I am making a rig in blender and have been looking at other rigs for inspiration. I came across an animator who's rig I really like. His rig has these smooth-like bends I can't see to replicate. This is what the smoothing looks like: [image: Minecraft rig smooth arms how?]

I might be overlooking a feature in blender, but I am pretty dumb and dont know all the tricks just yet. I am using Blender v2.90.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try bendy bones? Select your armature and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Viewport Display*, choose *B-Bone*. Then in *Edit* or *Pose* mode, select a bone and in in the *Properties panel > Bone > Bendy Bones*, increase the *Segments* amount:

[image]

Here is what it gives (compared to bones with one segment only), you can play with *Ease In* and *Ease Out* values:

[image]

You could also use more than 2 bones, some with one segment, others with several:

[image]

What you show is special though, as the outer sides are flat while the inner is round, so maybe a corrective shapekey for the inner curve and a driver to activate it?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely give that a try! Thanks!